# Крестики нолики на JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код игры крестики нолики, но здесь каждый выбор клетки делаю я сам, а каким образом можно сделать, чтобы против меня компьютер играл? Т.е один ход делаю я, один компьютер. Вот код:

```js
var pos = [
  [
    [0, 0],
    [0, 1],
    [0, 2]
  ], //1 строка
  [
    [1, 0],
    [1, 1],
    [1, 2]
  ], //2 строка
  [
    [2, 0],
    [2, 1],
    [2, 2]
  ], //3 строка

  [
    [0, 0],
    [1, 0],
    [2, 0]
  ], //1 столбец
  [
    [0, 1],
    [1, 1],
    [2, 1]
  ], //2 столбец
  [
    [0, 2],
    [1, 2],
    [2, 2]
  ], //3 столбец
];

function check() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var flag;

  for (var i = 0; i < pos.length; i++) {
    var win = true;
    for (var k = 0; k < pos[i].length; k++) {
      if (table.rows[pos[i][k][0]].cells[pos[i][k][1]].innerHTML !== 'X' && table.rows[pos[i][k][0]].cells[pos[i][k][1]].innerHTML !== 'O')
        win = false;
    }

    if (win) {
      flag = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (flag) {
    alert("победа");
  }
}

var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
  tds[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (this.innerHTML !== 'X') {
      this.innerHTML = 'X';
    } else {
      this.innerHTML = '';
    }
    check();
  })
}
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
  tds[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (this.innerHTML !== 'O') {
      this.innerHTML = 'O';
    } else {
      this.innerHTML = '';
    }
    check();
  })
}
```

```css
td {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: нужно добавить ход компьютера просто

Comment: @Grundy я добавлял, но не работает так. Все кнопки отключатся. Можете на данном примере показать?

Comment: Лучше покажи как добавлял :)

Comment: Добавь это непосредственно в вопрос, в комментариях код тяжело смотреть

Comment: @Grundy добавил. Посмотрите.

Comment: Посмотрел, у тебя подход неверный. Нужно не дополнительный обработчик вызывать, а вызывать функцию, которая поставить _куда-то_ ход компьютера и вызовет `check()`

Comment: Думаю этот пример поможет тебе разобраться https://codepen.io/cannanso/pen/vLNwmw

Comment: @Grundy куда именно, можете пояснить? долго мучаюсь. разобраться не могу

Comment: @NikitaSmith там очень много кода, не могли бы разъяснить на моем примере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения, нужно добавить функцию, которая бы эмулировала ход компьютера, например `stepComp` и вызывать ее после проверки хода игрока:

```
tds[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (this.innerHTML == '') {
    this.innerHTML = 'X';
    check();
    stepComp(tds);
  }
})
```

В данном примере функция принимает список ячеек, чтобы сделать ход.

Сама функция может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
function stepComp(tds) {
  for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    if (tds[i].innerHTML == '') {
      tds[i].innerHTML = 'O';
      check();
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

То есть, ищет первую свободную ячейку, ставит в нее 'O' и запускает проверку. Алгоритм выбора ячейки может меняться, но суть остается та же.

Пример в сборе: (не корректно работает метод проверки, так как проверяет просто отсутствие пустых ячеек, а не наличие конкретных символов)

```js
var pos = [
  [
    [0, 0],
    [0, 1],
    [0, 2]
  ], //1 строка
  [
    [1, 0],
    [1, 1],
    [1, 2]
  ], //2 строка
  [
    [2, 0],
    [2, 1],
    [2, 2]
  ], //3 строка

  [
    [0, 0],
    [1, 0],
    [2, 0]
  ], //1 столбец
  [
    [0, 1],
    [1, 1],
    [2, 1]
  ], //2 столбец
  [
    [0, 2],
    [1, 2],
    [2, 2]
  ], //3 столбец
];

function check() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var flag;

  for (var i = 0; i < pos.length; i++) {
    var win = true;
    for (var k = 0; k < pos[i].length; k++) {
      if (table.rows[pos[i][k][0]].cells[pos[i][k][1]].innerHTML !== 'X' && table.rows[pos[i][k][0]].cells[pos[i][k][1]].innerHTML !== 'O')
        win = false;
    }

    if (win) {
      flag = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (flag) {
    console.log("победа");
  }
}

var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
  tds[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (this.innerHTML == '') {
      this.innerHTML = 'X';
      check();
      stepComp(tds);
    }
  })
}

function stepComp(tds) {
  for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    if (tds[i].innerHTML == '') {
      tds[i].innerHTML = 'O';
      check();
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Некорректно флаг победы срабатывает, а так вроде хорошо)

Comment: @NikitaSmith, функция проверки не менялась, сейчас она проверяет отсутствие пустых ячеек, а не наличие определенных символов, это пояснение есть в ответе.